# *CSS Only* Images showing through open menu pane

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to get my open nav menu pane to display on top of the page content, mainly images. I've tried changing z-index but that only seems to make things worse.
Thanks for any help, this is for a school project (my first html/css class). I'm not sure if I need to also post the HTML here?

```
'''@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Libre+Caslon+Text:400,700&display=swap');

body {
  font-family: Libre Caslon Text;
  background-color: #FFAB91;
}

.body-text {
  padding-top: 20vh;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.hamburger-icon {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 5vh;
  left: 5vw;
  padding-bottom: 2vh;
}

.hamburger-icon span {
  height: 5px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: black;
  display: block;
  margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
  transition: 0.7s ease-in-out;
  transform: none;
}

#openmenu:checked~.menu-pane {
  left: -5vw;
  transform: translateX(-5vw);
}

#openmenu:checked~.body-text {
  display: none;
}

#openmenu:checked~.hamburger-icon span:nth-of-type(2) {
  transform: translate(0%, 175%) rotate(-45deg);
  background-color: white;
}

#openmenu:checked~.hamburger-icon span:nth-of-type(3) {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background-color: white;
}

#openmenu:checked~.hamburger-icon span:nth-of-type(1) {
  opacity: 0;
}

#openmenu:checked~.hamburger-icon span:nth-of-type(4) {
  opacity: 0;
}

div.menu-pane {
  background-color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-105vw);
  transform-origin: (0, 0);
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100%;
  transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.menu-pane p {
  color: black;
  font-size: 0.6em;
}

.menu-pane nav {
  padding: 10%;
}

.menu-links li,
a,
span {
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.menu-pane ul {
  padding: 10%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.menu-pane li {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-size: 1em;
}


.menu-pane li:first-child {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  margin-left: -10px;
}


.menu-links li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}


.menu-links li:hover a {
  color: #FFAB91;
}

.menu-links li:first-child:hover a {
  color: black;
  background-color: #FFAB91;
}

#eug-info {
  background-color: #FFAB91;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-color: #FFAB91;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;

}

.menu-links li:first-child:hover #eug-info {
  opacity: 1;
}

.menu-links li:first-child:hover #spring-info {
  opacity: 1;
}

#spring-info {
  background-color: #FFAB91;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-color: #FFAB91;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
}


.menu-links li:first-child a {
  padding: 5px;
}

input.hamburger-checkbox {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  top: 5vh;
  left: 5vw;
  width: 10vw;
  opacity: 0;
  height: 6vh;
}'''
```

[Images showing through open menu pane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ta2jI.png)

Comment: I was able to get it to work by adding 'img{
  display: block;
  z-index: -1;
}'

Comment: try to use a positive z-index instead of negative. What I mean by that is, put the element that's supposed to be above a higher z-index instead. Great job in solving your issue.